# SQL count - showing week range as column headers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, pivot, date-range

i have the following sql

```
    SELECT    COUNT(*) as Total, SentByText
FROM     letterCase WITH (nolock)
WHERE     (SenttoClientDate BETWEEN DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),0) AND DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),6))
group by SentByText
```

this counts all records that match criterea and displays results like

```
Total       SentByText
    5          Fred
    4          Colin
    2          Bob
    1          Billy
```

my question is how would i get results to show like this - having the date range as column headers

```
SentByText    10/10/2016  11/10/2016  12/10/2016  13/10/2016  
 fred              4           5           2          2           
 colin             7           2           0          2                  
 bob               2           1          12          6                 
 billy             9           0           0          2
```

ive looked at  using a pivot but not sure how i go about showing dates without hardcoding

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic sql see [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) for example. The only essential difference from other dynamic pivots is the way you create column list using tally table (sys.all_objects here):

```
declare @cols varchar(max) = 
         stuff(
             (select top(7)  ','+quotename(convert(varchar(12),DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), row_number() over(order by (select null)) -1) ,103))
                from sys.all_objects for xml path(''))
             ,1,1,'')

select @cols;
```

Don't forget to convert pivoted date the same way in dynamic query `.. dt = convert(varchar(12),SenttoClientDate),103) ..`